# I'm having problems with a CSS/HTML checkbox nested inside ul, li elements

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm having problems with HTML/CSS checkbox. I have code written to have a checkbox in a set of ul/li elements. The problem is if I click on the text of any of the li elements it crosses off the first ingredient on the list instead of crossing off the li element you clicked on. The checkbox itself works fine besides this hiccup. Any suggestions or ideas on whats going on and how I can fix this?

```css
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: black;
  font-style: normal;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">2(6 ounce) filet mignon steaks</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">1 teaspoon olive oil</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">Coarse kosher salt and freshly ground black pepper</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">1/2 cup red wine of your choice</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">2 tablespoons of butter</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">Oven proof skillet/ Cast-iron skillet</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">Oven mitts!</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">Thermometer</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Every checkbox id should be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because each of the `<label>` `for`s are for the same `name`: they all target the name `ossm`.

This defaults to the first `ossm` element, and so they each are for the first `<label>`.

To fix this, have a unique `name` (and the same `<label for>`) for each checkbox.

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">2(6 ounce) filet mignon steaks</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm2" name="ossm2">
    <label for="ossm2">1 teaspoon olive oil</label>
</li>
```

---

Also, you should not have each of them have `id="ossm"`. [ID's are supposed to be unique.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/127180)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm gonna bash my head against a wall for being stupid.

Comment: @powerup7 I'm glad I helped (don't forget to accept if I did!)

Comment: And @powerup7 don't bang your head. That'll probably hurt. Instead, feel good by upvoting and/or accepting my answer! Thanks!

Comment: @powerup7 I see you are somewhat new to SO. Accepting an answer means clicking the green check mark below the number to the left of the answer. When you get a few more reputation points, you will also be able to vote it up.

Comment: The label's `for` attribute connects to the inputs `ID` attribute, not `name`. Because, like you mentioned, IDs have to be unique whereas names don't necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same name and id in every input element! It needs to be a different one for each input.

Comment: @BrianWillis: Not only is this an answer, it's *correct*. Please be more careful in evaluating answers in review.

Answer (score -1):

Your are required to amend the for attribute and id unique 
HTML Code

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm">2(6 ounce) filet mignon steaks</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm1" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm1">1 teaspoon olive oil</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm2" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm2">Coarse kosher salt and freshly ground black pepper</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm3" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm3">1/2 cup red wine of your choice</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm4" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm4">2 tablespoons of butter</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm5" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm5">Oven proof skillet/ Cast-iron skillet</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm6" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm6">Oven mitts!</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ossm7" name="ossm">
    <label for="ossm7">Thermometer</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css code

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: black;
  font-style: normal;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Avoid code-only answers. Please edit and add an explanation.

Comment: also the name needs to be different - it's relevant for sending the data when submitting the form

Comment: I am not talking about the CSS or HTML, I am talking about the post or get submission to the next page and the way the sent data are received / read out there ($_POST['name1'], $_POST['name2'] etc.).

Comment: its out of scope my friend...the answer you provide is partially correct you need to change keep id as unique..

Comment: I wrote "also the name..." = ID _and_ name

Comment: okay no worries...but don't make others answers not useful...unless the question owner decided what would be the most suite to him or her..